# session.subscribe throws error when called in onMount

Tags: sveltekit

```
<script>

  import {onMount} from 'svelte';
  import {session} from "$app/stores"
  import {writable} from 'svelte/store';

  const store = writable('some value');

  let value = null

  onMount(() => {

   // this works
   // return store.subscribe( (storeValue) => {value = storeValue}); // this works
   
   // this throws an error:
   // return session.subscribe( (sessionValue) => {value = sessionValue}); 
   // Uncaught (in promise) Error: Function called outside component initialization

  });

</script>
```

can someone please explain to me the problem with session.subscribe and why it keeps throwing?

if I move session.subscribe outside onMount it runs fine.

***Note: this code is part of a SvelteKit Project, inside a Svelte component, not a SvelteKit page/route.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What goes wrong

It seems that you are actually experiencing intended behaviour. Under the [documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-stores) for `$app/stores` you will find this:

> Stores are contextual — they are added to the context of your root component. This means that session and page are unique to each request on the server, rather than shared between multiple requests handled by the same server simultaneously, which is what makes it safe to include user-specific data in session.
> Because of that, you must subscribe to the stores during component initialization (which happens automatically if you reference the store value, e.g. as $page, in a component) before you can use them.

When you were attempting this, you probably got a callstack that looks something like this:

```bash
Error: Function called outside component initialization
    at get_current_component (index.mjs:953:15)
    at getContext (index.mjs:989:12) <----------Here is the problem
    at getStores (stores.js:19:17)
    at Object.subscribe (stores.js:70:17)
    at index.svelte:10:13
    at run (index.mjs:18:12)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at index.mjs:1816:45
    at flush (index.mjs:1075:17)
    at init (index.mjs:1908:9)
```

We can see that Svelte attempts to call `getContext` when you subscribe to the session. Calling `getContext` outside of the component root is not allowed, which causes the subscription to fail.

I agree that this is quite unintuitive and I am not really sure why they implemented it this way.

### Workaround

By the way, are you really sure you only want to subscribe to `session` on mount? What are you trying to do?

If you really only want to subscribe to `session` after component mount, you could use this workaround: Create your own store that updates whenever the session changes, then listen to that.

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import { session } from "$app/stores";
  import { writable } from "svelte/store";

  let mySession = writable($session);
  $: $mySession = $session;

  onMount(()=>{
      mySession.subscribe(...whatever...);
  })

</script>
```

Comment: I was trying to return the unsubscribe method to onMount to have the component unsubscribe automatically onDestroy. 

I know using the $session will just do the subscribe and unsubscribe automatically, but if I want to pass in a callback with specific logic, I was wondering how that can be done. 

I completely missed that little detail about getContext. Thank you for your time to point it out. I'm going to read more about it.